# Ubuntu 20.04 - Connect to OpenVPN via the GUI instead of command line

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

Currently I am connecting to the work's OpenVPN using the command line:

```
sudo openvpn --config work.ovpn --auth-user-pass --auth-retry interact
```

**work.ovpn** is the certificates file. **interact** is for Duo app 2FA.

This works great.

Now, I don't want to connect to the VPN using the command line, I want to use the built-in GUI. I go to **Settings > Network > VPN > + > Import from file** and giving it the same **work.ovpn** file. Saving right away without changing nothing else. It does connects to the VPN but all the hosts that outside the VPN network are not available. I mean google.com and askubuntu.com etc.

What I am doing wrong? I need to configure something else? Please help.

Comment: When creating a new VPN, I've seen the option of "Use this connection only for resources on its network", maybe edit your connection and make sure that's not checked, for both ipv4 and ipv6. If that doesn't help, try connecting to a website using an IP address, if that works, then your DNS server is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem -- I can connect my openvpn server via command line, but cannot make it via gnome-control-center (gnome-network-manager).
And I find advanced settings in authentication and very soon to find TCP connection is checked.

After I un-check TCP connection, I can connect my openvpn-server now.

To be short:
check options in advanced settings, it could help in my case.
[image: advanced settings]